# how to convert string into it's "html" ascii code using Java?

Tags: java

e.g.

```
&#66; is uppercase B.
so if I have string like "BOY". I want it converted to &#66;&#79;&#89;
```

I'm hoping there's already a library I can use. I've searched the net but I didn't see it.

thanks

Comment: Ready Made UTIL class :http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-character-to-ascii-in-java/

Comment: @sureshatta: please don't use "ASCII" here. ASCII is pretty much irrelevant these days and using it in those places gives the wrong impressions. You are *either* referencing unicode codepoints *or* bytes in some encoding (that's possibly *based on* ASCII, but almost **never** ASCII itself these days).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try writing your own utility:

```
String input = "BOY";
char[] chars = input.toCharArray();

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

for (char c : chars)
{
    output.append("&#").append((int) c).append(";");
}
```

output content after execution:

```
&#66;&#79;&#89;
```

Comment: @GaborSch I know it, but the intention is just to give a solution idea to the OP, and I think my answer does it. if the performance issues come into discussion, of course you are right. so can you remove your downvote?

Comment: OP is beginner, don't teach improper patterns. The vote is locked, if you use StringBuilder, I'll remove the downvote of course.

Answer (score 7):

Those codes are nothing but concatenation of `&#` and `;` with the Unicode Codepoint for each character. You can iterate over each character in the string, and do:

```
output.append("&#")
   .append((int)ch)
   .append(";");
```

Where, `output` refers to a `StringBuilder` instance.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's the Unicode codepoint (since HTML4 and in pretty much every modern environment). Please don't spread the "ASCII" mis-information. ASCII is pretty much irrelevant these days.

Comment: @JoachimSauer One question on this approach: if my understanding is correct, this way is not going to give Unicode code point, but UTF-16BE representation.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @AdrianShum: well, yes. It returns a "UTF-16 codepoint" which is equivalent to the "Unicode codepoint" *if and only if* the character is in the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). If it is not, you need to use the `codePointAt` method of `String` and you'll get the real Unicode codepoint.